# IE7 div (within a container) gap and misalisgnment problem

Tags: css, layout, html, internet-explorer-7

I'm having an issue where IE7 simply will not display my DIV's properly..Firefox 3, Safari, Opera, Chrome, IE8 and even IE6 (with some JS help) display the page fine, but for some reason, in IE7 the footer seems to be...outside of the container.  You can clearly see a gap between the footer and the #content div in the below screenshot.  There is also some misalignment from the #information div down.

[image: IE7 div gap issue]

The link to the live site is: http://chronologic.ath.cx.

I can almost guarantee the issue is caused by my complete lack of understanding of CSS, so I apologize for the messy bloated markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just took a quick look, but you may want to rethink applying `height: 100%` to div#container. Older versions of IE frequently don't behave as expected and take 100% to mean the width or height of the page, not the container that it is in. I can't verify this though without further investigation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an issue of [clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) because both elements inside of `#footer` are floated. Try adding `#footer { overflow:hidden; }`.

Comment: This is what I was thinking too, but the issue still reoccurred after removing the clear div.  Oh well, I'm sure the overflow:hidden can't hurt.  Either way, it ended up being the height: 100% on the container div.  Thanks for the quick response Marcel!

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:hidden` `clear:both` and making sure you have reset your HTML with `html { padding: 0; margin: 0;}` should fix it